# Going from SNAPSHOT to RELEASE?

Tags: maven, release, nexus

I've a quick question - I've built my first Jenkins / Maven solution and currently have it set up so it's happily checking out form svn, deploying my code and then checking in the built artefacts to nexus. (mvn deploy:deploy-file  with it's own pom)
To do this I'm using a version of 1.0-SNAPSHOT in the pom's and so everything is going into the nexus repo under snapshots - which I'm happy with.
Once testing is completed - I want to send these artefacts to Release.

So what's the best way to take this forward ?

Comment: Maven release plugin. It has its faults, but I don't know of a better way. Is that all you were asking?

Comment: i agree. maven-release-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Do NOT use deploy-file. A normal mvn deploy is what you want to use for your project
2. From a pure deployment point of view all you need to do is change the version of your projects so they dont end in -SNAPSHOT and have a repository defined in distributionManagement.
3. The Maven relese plugin can help with SCM integration and so on but it is NOT required.

You can find ready to try projects in the [Nexus book examples](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples) with more description in the [eval chapter of the Nexus documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval-proxy-publish.html).

There is also a [good blog post with a full example](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/02/25/build-binaries-only-once-for-continuous-deployment/) available from Arun Gupta and myself with [the source code on github](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-simple-sample).

Comment: The link to Arun's blog post no longer works, but the post is still available [here](https://planet.jboss.org/post/build_binaries_only_once_for_continuous_deployment), [here](https://progressivewebexperience.io/blog/arun_gupta/2015/02/build_binaries_only_once_for_continuous_deployment), and [here](https://dzone.com/articles/build-binaries-only-once-for-continuous-deployment).  Unfortunately the pictures are no longer there at any of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nexus Enterprise you have a staging area where you can promote your snapshots to Release. If you are using Community Edition then maven-release-plugin is your option and obviously you can automate this in Jenkins.